# Saving Siri INCreateNoteIntent in coredata

Tags: swift3, siri, sirikit

I know Siri is setup correctly, hence the image below. But the content is not saving in core data. Siri said it created the note, but it's not showing in coredata. This is what I tried so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INCreateNoteIntentHandling {

func handle(intent: INCreateNoteIntent, completion: @escaping (INCreateNoteIntentResponse) -> Void) {

    let context = Context.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newNote = Notes(context: context)
    newNote.textView = intent.content?.description
  //  newNote.textView = intent.title?.spokenPhrase

    // Save the context

    do {
        try context.save()

        let response = INCreateNoteIntentResponse(code: INCreateNoteIntentResponseCode.success, userActivity: nil)

        response.createdNote = INNote(title: intent.title!, contents: [intent.content!], groupName: nil, createdDateComponents: nil, modifiedDateComponents: nil, identifier: nil)

        completion(response)
    } catch {

        completion(INCreateNoteIntentResponse(code: INCreateNoteIntentResponseCode.failure, userActivity: nil))
    }

}



func confirm(intent: INCreateNoteIntent, completion: @escaping (INCreateNoteIntentResponse) -> Void) {

    completion(INCreateNoteIntentResponse(code: INCreateNoteIntentResponseCode.ready, userActivity: nil))
}



public func resolveContent(for intent: INCreateNoteIntent, with completion: @escaping (INNoteContentResolutionResult) -> Swift.Void) {
    let result: INNoteContentResolutionResult

    if let content = intent.content {
        result = INNoteContentResolutionResult.success(with: content)


    } else {

        result = INNoteContentResolutionResult.needsValue()
    }

    completion(result)
}
```

}

Whenever I tried to save a note
[image]

Comment: It's because your Siri extension is not the same as your application. Siri extension and application save data to two different files.

Comment: you have to put both the application and Siri extension into same application group and place your core data's SQL file in this group. Look for what is application group in the Apple's documentation.